# Elasticsearch - include child document if it exists

Tags: elasticsearch, parent-child, elasticsearch-5

I have document type "A" which is a parent of type "B". Not all "A"s have children documents, though. I would like to get all documents of type "A" matching certain filters, and I would also like to include "B" as an inner hit, if B exists. Is it possible to do in ElasticSearch 5.5? Just using has_child would not return any document "A" that has no child.

Comment: closely related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48798104/elasticsearch-get-count-of-child-docs-even-if-count-is-zero

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by running a bool query with 2 should conditions:

1. Parents which have no children of type B (using not + has_child)
2. Parents which have children of type B (using has_child + inner_hits)

This works as expected and returns all parents, irrespectively if they have child B or not, and includes B data if B exists.